# sharing source between Linux eclipse and MS Visual Studio

Tags: linux, eclipse, visual-studio, svn, windows-xp

I have a linux eclipse project checked into our company svn.  Works great.

The project is intended to be cross compiled on Windows.

Untill now, I have simply moved the source files between OSes.  However, I thought I'd like to let svn do this for me.  Should be simple enough, just checkout the eclipse linux src into the VS project dir, right?   Wrong!

The correct source was checked out of svn and it worked fine.  But when I tried to check it back in i kept getting "Commit not completed *filename* remains in conflict" errors.  I hadn't even changed anything!

Did a little checking.  Turns out the linux src directory is pretty much just the source and headers.  On the MSVS side the project directory contains the source and headers but also contains a bunch of files that are used by VS with names like projname.vcproj etc. etc.

So, I did a checkout into a scratch dirextory, .\fred.  Checked .\fred back in.  No problems.  Added a new file to .fred, xxx.xxx.  Check in reported:

```
svn: E200009: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200009: 'C:\Projects\fred\xxx.xxx' is not under version control
```

Makes me wonder about those uncommitted Visual Studio files.

So, are those files my problem?  Are they breaking the commit operation?

As an alternate solution I am thinking of adding the VS files to the src dir in svn.  If linux/eclipse checks them out I can tell eclipse to ignore them (I think it'll just ignore them for me).  Any thoughts or recommendations for this approach?

(BTW, i still had fresh source on the linux side so any thing that got clobbered could be safely restored.)

Comment: Did you svn add the MSVS files?

Comment: I would separate the MSVC files from the sources (i.e. put them in different directories) so you can check them in and out independently.

Comment: @ArneMertz Please help my ignorance: can I checkout (and checkin) two projects into the same one directory?  As in svn co "......\src" fred  followed by  svn co "....\MSVS" fred    where fred is the client side dir in a VS project?  This would be a GREAT solution!

Comment: @JesusRamos NOt yet.  Awaiting advice.  Really like Arne Mertz idea for that!

Comment: @ArneMertz The answer appears to be "no".  At least from my quick and dirty test

Comment: @WesMiller I fail to see how and why you would want two projects in the same directory. Could you give some more information what that projects would be and the structure of your direcotry tree?

Comment: @ArneMertz Only one project in one directory.  The goal is to have MSVS C++ share identical source code with eclipse on Linux.  The problem is that Windows has all those vcproj files in the source dir and eclipse would be clueless about then.  The same would be true in reverse since MSVC would be clueless about ,project and .cproject files.  What I am trying to do is put just the source in the src (svn) dir and have the vcproj files in another.  If I really needed to ever checkout the vcproj files, I;d have to sheck out into a dummy dir and copy it's contents into the src (client) dir.

Comment: Well, so whats the problem with that? For example, I have a project where the sources are situated under meow/src/cpp, and the visual studio project and solution files under meow/vsproject. Eclipse project files would go into meow/ecproject - you get the idea. Is there a problem getting that structure into svn, maybe using svn externals or other features? It has been a time since I worked with svn, so I might be missing something there - DVCSes are so much more fun ;-)

Comment: guess I don't know enough about how VS builds and sees directories.  This may clearly be the right answer desppite my efforts (see answer from me).

Comment: We use CMake for such cross-platform stuff.

Comment: @dreamzor - i have no skills there.  If cmake had an IDE or even a graphical setup tool, it'd help.  Od does it?

Comment: I suppose another approach is using eclipse on Windows, but I have no idea on how to set it up so my code compiles to work like the VS output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is one solution I have working for the moment.  I am not sure how totally stable it is.

Caveat:  The project i am using already existed as a MSVS project.

In the MSVS solution dir, rename the source dir (MSVS likes the source dir name to match the solution dir name, so this means the source dir may not be named src) to something uninvolved in the solution, like *temp*.

SVN checkout the src (eclipse like to call source dirs *src*).

cd into the source dir.  Issue the command:

```
svn changelist msvs *.cpp *.h
```

Add *.c if needed.  "msvs" is the changelist name.  It can be whatever you want ti to be.

This will created a changelist for the checked out directory.

Now, copy the remaining files from the *temp* directory into your source dir.

When you need to do a checkin, cd into the source dir and issue this command:

```
svn ci --changelist msvs
```

Note.  You have to be in the src dir for this to work.